# SharePoint view issues

Tags: list-view, filter

I'm having some issues on a SharePoint list view. I have a people picker column "Work Allocated" and have enabled the Folders in the list view. I'm creating folders for each month and I would want the users to go to the respective month folder and update the info.

Since I don't want the users to see other user entries, I used the filter `Work Allocated = [Me]`

Though it's showing me the items, I'm unable to see the Folders.

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders are also counted as Items and as such filter rules also apply to them.

Since the folder does not have the user on the column it is not showing it to them.

What you can do is add another filter  (using OR) and set the logic to show content type Folder. This means it will show ALL folders as well as all items that have the user = Work Allocated

Comment: Thank you buddy. It did work as expected. The rule is Content Type = Folder OR Work Allocated = [Me]